# How do I implement Vertical Pod Autoscaling in Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 (v1809) machine with Kubernetes (bundled with Docker Desktop for Windows). I want to enable Vertical Pod Autoscaling for the cluster I have created.

However, all the documentation I can find is either for a [cloud service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler) or a [Linux-based system](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler). Is it possible to implement VPA for the Docker Desktop Kubernetes in Windows or Minikube?

Comment: Were you able to complete this ?  If yes, kindly let me know how did you do it

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you want to try yourself you need to start by converting all the scripts under [hack/](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/hack) into Batch / Powershell and build the VPA daemon using that.

Answer (score 1):

While VPA itself is a daemon, the pods it controls are just API objects as far it knows and can be anything on any platform. As for compiling a VPA container for Windows, I wouldn't expect any problems, you'll just need to build it yourself since we don't provide one.